# Personal GitHub subscriptions in Slack like we have for Teams

Tags: github, slack

In Microsoft Teams I can add the GitHub app (after it has been approved by my org admin), then a seperate GitHub bot channel appears and I can subscribe to a number of repository events.

However I do not see the same functionality available in the Slack GitHub integration. My Slack org admin has added the GitHub integration however it appears that I can only invite and subscribe on existing channels that have many members opposed to having the ability to subscribe just for myself like I can with the Teams GitHub integration.

Is this a limitation of the Slack GitHub integration or am I missing something (potentially associated with lack of user permissions)?

Comment: ["*Once you install the app, you can not interact with GitHub app as a Personal app or access from a channel.*"](https://github.com/integrations/slack). Seems like it's a limitation.

Answer (score -1):

The solution we found was to allow users to create their own private channels with only themselves as members, then they can `/invite @GitHub` to their own private channel and subscribe to what they want to see.